# On the research fertility of Arithmetic Topology.

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, arithmetic-topology

I'm thinking about doing my Master's Thesis on the subject of Arithmetic Topology: the relation between knots and primes, 3-manifolds and number fields, and other connections between topology and number theory (based on the works of B. Mazur, M. Morishita et al.).

I've talked about it with my topology professor and he thinks it's an interesting subject but he does not know if there is enough room in the subject for me to add something new to it.

There seems to be a very small amount of books and articles on the subject and that leads him to believe that there's nothing new and of significance to discover (at least with the mathematical tools that exist today).

I'm not versed enough in the subject to answer that but perhaps one of you can confirm or deny my professor's opinion.

Comment: If you are looking to prove something novel in the field, perhaps mathoverflow might be the place to ask this question.

Comment: I assume that the typo in the tag name has been around long enough so that other users can check that [the related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297167) has been corrected. So I guess you could change the tag name to only one hyphen. (Of course, I could to it too - but I think you deserve the credit for creating the tag. If the tag stays, there is [Taxonomist badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) and also [Research assistant badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/176/research-assistant) etc.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for bringing this to my attention. When I created the tag I intended for only one hyphen, but I must have done something wrong. I noticed it a few seconds later and then tried to edit it but I could only edit the description of the tag and not the tag itself.

Comment: @DarthGeek Since this is only a technical issue related to tagging (and not to your actual question) I'd suggest to move the discussion about changing the tag [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38316130#38316130).

Comment: Is your advisor suggesting a different problem to work on?

Comment: @littleO Not really. It's a beautiful and interesting subject so a master's thesis can come out of it either way, but it would be better if it had some relevance in the world of research. It would be different if it was a PhD thesis, of course.